# One LINQ query to get counts from several entities when using entity framework core

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Im working on the LINQ query which returns counts from several entities. 
I created this kind of query:

```
public async Task<(int UsersCount, int GuestUsersCount, int WorkItemsCount, int WorkGroupsCount)> GetSiteInfoAsync()
{
    var counters = await (from user in Context.UserAccounts
                            from guestUser in Context.GuestAccounts
                            from workItem in Context.WorkItems
                            from workGroup in Context.WorkGroups
                            select new
                            {
                                usersCount = Context.UserAccounts.Count(),
                                guestUsersCount = Context.GuestAccounts.Count(),
                                workGroupsCount = Context.WorkGroups.Where(x => x.IsActive).Count(),
                                workItemsCount = Context.WorkItems.Count()
                            }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return (counters.usersCount, counters.guestUsersCount, counters.workItemsCount, counters.workGroupsCount);
}
```

I found the query blows up in case if the `WorkItem` table is empty. I tried a different thing where I removed this part of code from the query:

```
from guestUser in Context.GuestAccounts
from workItem in Context.WorkItems
from workGroup in Context.WorkGroups
```

and then the query worked, cuz in my case I know that the `UserAccounts` table is never empty as there is always some default User in the DB:

```
var counters = await (from user in Context.UserAccounts
                        select new
                        {
                            usersCount = Context.UserAccounts.Count(),
                            guestUsersCount = Context.GuestAccounts.Count(),
                            workGroupsCount = Context.WorkGroups.Where(x => x.IsActive).Count(),
                            workItemsCount = Context.WorkItems.Count()
                        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Im just wondering if there is a cleaner solution?
It needs to be a one LINQ query only. I also thought about creating a SQL view but this would be nasty for me as I would need to create separate migration for it and anytime I have to add some changes to 
the code I need to update the view with a new migration.
Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: and why not `var usersCount  = await Context.UserAccounts.CountAsync(); var guestUsersCount = await .... return (userCount, guestUsersCount , ....);` ? one query doesn't make sens(in this case) as on sql side it will execute one by one

Comment: `var usersCount = await Context.UserAccounts.CountAsync();` I was thinking the same thing.  Couldn't figure out how the tables were related.

Comment: @Selvin The only difference is that OP's query happens in one call from the client to the database. But I consider this way of creating a query "batch" a bit hacky.

Comment: Can you share your models? @GoldenAge

Comment: @FurkanÖztürk what for? To simplify the problem you can treat that there is no dependency between the entities

Comment: @Selvin ok, I think I will just follow your advice. Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering if there is really no way to translate the sql eg. `SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   WorkItem) AS [WorkItemCount],
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   WorkGroup) AS [WorkGroupCount]` to the LINQ query. It would be the one call only..

Comment: I dont think you would save much issuing one call or one for each count.

Answer (score 0):

That's a one LINQ query solution, i hope this will be helpful,

```
var result = Context.UserAccounts.Select(x => new List<int>() { 1, 0, 0, 0 }).Union(Context.GuestAccounts.Select(y => new List<int>() { 0, 1, 0, 0 }))
            .Union(Context.WorkGroups.Where(x => x.IsActive).Select(z => new List<int>() { 0, 0, 1, 0 })).Union(Context.WorkItems.Select(t => new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0, 1 })).ToList();
```

After database request you can get the count the occurences as shown below,

```
var count1 = result.Where(x => x[0] == 1).Count();
var count2 = result.Where(x => x[1] == 1).Count();
var count3 = result.Where(x => x[2] == 1).Count();
var count4 = result.Where(x => x[3] == 1).Count();
```

Comment: One word: overengineering.

Comment: I am aware of that, just trying to provide question's requirements :)